# React App frontend does not recognize my Golang Backend

Tags: reactjs, go, cpanel

I am trying to deploy a React-app with a Golang backend on cpanel.

The steps I have followed are:

1. Compiled Golang app into a linux executable + uploaded to
   public_html in cpanel
2. Added website name to package.json file
3. Ran the `npm run build` to produce a build folder
4. Uploaded and unzipped inside of public html
5. Ran the golang executable on console of cpanel with `PORT=1234 ./app-name`

Result: static part of website works, but does not connect to backend - data is not showing

I can't seem to find where I have gone wrong, I've tried following all the guides without much luck.

Would be extremely grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: does your api answer requests? via curl or postman

Comment: communication between backend and website seems completely dead - console debug prints do not reflect any user actions. I'm using pusher for comms between frontend and backend